# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password) ssh error

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Heads up I'm a noob with linux and networking.

I set up a ubuntu server and I have a static ip for my network. When I try to connect to the server at home (external), it prompts me to log in. I supply the correct password (or incorrect pw), I get the error `Permission denied, please try again.`

and after 3 times I get

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password)
```

I am however able to connect with SSH from another computer in the same network with `ssh < internal ip of server >`

I'm connecting with mac os x and my config file is vanilla.

Note: During installation of ubuntu it says I don't have a default route or something while doing auto network configuration, but I ignored it and continued the installation, could this be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I have tried the below, I have nothing in `hosts.allow` and also iptables shows the ports that I have allowed, which is 22.

I checked the `auth.log`, and there is nothing when I connect to it remotely (even when it says permission denied). I have tried connecting to it internally and the correct authentication logs show. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `iptables -L -v -n`?

Comment: I believe I have found the problem. The network admin forwarded the ports to the wrong destination, 192.168.1.253 when the server is at 192.168.1.8. Still kind of weird because it seemed like I was able to connect to the ubuntu server with the correct username at login. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's why you're supposed to check the fingerprint when it says "The authenticity of host ________ can't be established." - so that you're not just sending your password to a random machine.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your ssh server is only allow login from specific IP. Check `/etc/hosts.allow` if you see something like this:

```
sshd: IP
```

Also check if you have `iptables` is running:

```
iptables -L -v -n
```

Take a look at `/var/log/auth.log`, it will tell you more details.

Comment: thanks I'll check it tomorrow, but what do I do if it `/etc/hosts.allow` shows `sshd: IP`?

Comment: Remove that line if you want to allow login from any IP.